# When cloning, change selected option in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is what I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/XSX8G/1/

Now, you can see all the selected options are Blue.

This should only apply to the FIRST select.

So then there's 3 remains, and I wish to load from the ChosenOptions array:

```
var chosenOptions = ['Black', 'Red', 'Black'];
```

So the first loop should take the option that has value "Black" and mark to SELECTED.

Then the second loop it should be the "Red" selected, and third loop it should be Black again.

Which does that when it is done loading it has these as Marked in the 4 selects:

```
Blue, Black, Red, Black
```

How can I do this? This should not be made static for only just 3 array keys, and it should not forget the selected values when you increase from 4 to 5..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd count your choose options array and then iterate over if as you clone. If the loop for cloning is larger than the options array we just reset the counter. http://jsfiddle.net/XSX8G/3/

```
        var chosenOptions = ['Black', 'Red', 'Black'];
        var optionsCount = chosenOptions.length
            var y =0

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(amount - selectCount); i++) {
               var clone = $orig.clone(true, true);
               $orig.after(clone);
            if(y >= optionsCount){y= 0}
                    //reset counter to start at the beginning
            clone.val(chosenOptions[y])
                ++y
        }
```